# Kendo MVC Grid not passing parent ID to ClientID Template, when creating Child record

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having a problem adding a child record in my hierarchical grid.  It won't pass over the HeaderId from the parent in the grid.

Can anyone spot an issue, or am I trying to do something that isn't possible?
Thanks.

Here's the controller action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult BillDetail_Create(BillDetail billDetail, int billHeaderId)
        {
            if (billHeaderId == 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("billHeaderID", "add bill header first");
            }
            if (billDetail != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var target = new BillDetail
                {
                    Category = billDetail.Category,
                    Description = billDetail.Description,
                    Amount = billDetail.Amount,
                    BillHeaderId = billHeaderId,
                    BillDetailId = SessionBillDetails.Max(d => d.BillDetailId) + 1
                };

                //Get next Id in sequence

                billDetail.BillDetailId = target.BillDetailId;

                SessionBillDetails.Add(target);
            }

            return Json(new[] { billDetail }.ToDataSourceResult(new DataSourceRequest(), ModelState));
        }
```

And here's the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BillHeader>()

    .Name("BillHeaders")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(h => h.BillHeaderId);
        columns.Bound(h => h.Category);
        columns.Bound(h => h.Description);
        columns.Bound(h => h.Amount);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
            .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(6)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("BillHeaders_Read", "Bill"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("BillDetails")

      )

<script id="BillDetails" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BillDetail>()
          .Name("BillDetails_#=BillHeaderId#")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(d => d.BillHeaderId).Width(50);
              columns.Bound(d => d.BillDetailId).Width(70);
              columns.Bound(d => d.Category).Width(70);
              columns.Bound(d => d.Description).Width(150);
              columns.Bound(d => d.Amount).Width(80);
              columns.Command(command =>
              {
                  command.Edit();
                  command.Destroy();
              }).Width(75);
          })
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(10)
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(d => d.BillDetailId);
                  model.Field(d => d.BillDetailId).Editable(false);
              })
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("BillDetails_Read", "Bill", new { billHeaderId = "#=BillHeaderId#" }))
            .Update(update => update.Action("BillDetail_Update", "Bill"))
            **.Create(create => create.Action("BillDetail_Create", "Bill", new { billHeaderId = "#=BillHeaderId#" }))**
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("BillDetail_Destroy", "Bill")))

          .Pageable()
          .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
          .ToClientTemplate()
          )
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to finally fix this.  Unbelievable really....

I named the parameter in my controller (and view) to be "**id**"

So Controller:

```
        public ActionResult BillDetail_Create(BillDetail billDetail, int id)
```

And View:

```
        .Read(read => read.Action("BillDetails_Read", "Bill", new { id = "#=BillHeaderId#" }))
        .Update(update => update.Action("BillDetail_Update", "Bill"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("BillDetail_Create", "Bill", new { id = "#=BillHeaderId#" }))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("BillDetail_Destroy", "Bill")))
```

Comment: Thank you David. I was running into the same issue and changing naming the parameter to id fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For a better explanation of why that worked:

This can occur if the BillDetail class has a property with the same name. In this case the MVC model binder will override the value sent with the request route values with the value sent as form data for the grid model. If this is the case then the simplest option to avoid the problem would be to rename the parameter.  that is why renaming to ID worked.